# Call setInterval or setTimeout with a list of timings?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am not good with javascript, so excuse me if my question is illformed.

I try to make a playfunction for recorded midi "timed events" they are recorded using performance.now, ideally i would like setInterval to take an array as parameter list :). 
But i guess that is not possible. I can not figure out howto use setInterval or setTimeout with my array of timings. I precalculate the difference in time between following events and store before playing, but it seem setInterval do not change, maybe i have to clear it everytime before i set a new timing?

Any help appreciated, probably setInterval or setTimeout not ideal for execute sendnote using the list of timings?

```
function play(){
lastelement=track[0].midiMess.length;
var x=0; 
var waitEv=new Array();
//INIT FIRST EVENT
waitEv[x]=track[0].midiMess[x].time;
x++;
//LOOP THRU ALL EVENTS CALCULATE TIMEDIFFERENCES
while(x<lastelement){
    waitEv[x]=track[0].midiMess[x].time-track[0].midiMess[x-1].time;
    x++;
}
y=0;
playin=setInterval(playEvent,waitEv[y]);
}

function playEvent(){
noteOnMessage = [track[0].midiMess[y].data0,track[0].midiMess[y].data1,track[0].midiMess[y].data2];
output.send(noteOnMessage);  
y++;
if (y==lastelement) clearInterval(playin);
}
```

Comment: You could just daisy chain setTimeout's.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use setInterval, another option is chaining setTimeout's instead.

Here is an example of doing this.

ps. please note setTimeouts & setInterval have certain limitations on accuracy, if you find this is not accurate enough, another option is using some high performance timers,..

```js
var waitlist = [1000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 2000, 1000];

function doWait() {
    if (waitlist.length) {
        var waittime = waitlist.shift();
        console.log("Waiting: " + waittime);
        setTimeout(doWait, waittime);
    }
}

//boostrap our wait loops
doWait();
```

Comment: Any chance you could show me how to do it with performance now? I can not quite see how the actual timer can be set to waitstate, you would have to poll it?

Comment: `while(x<lastelement)`  Indeed, this will block the main thread.  Use a setInterval to do your poling and you should be good to go.